# NSMutableURLRequest adding additional headers in url only for iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsmutableurlrequest, iphone-6

This is appears only on iOS 8. For earlier versions, it is fine.

Examples:

For iOS 7.1:

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.example.com/api/search?name=test&page=1";
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[urlRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Getting `urlRequest` as

```
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7b787130> { URL: http://www.example.com/api/search?name=test&page=1 }
```

For iOS 8.0:

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.example.com/api/search?name=test&page=1";
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[urlRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Getting `urlRequest` as

```
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7b6246d0> { URL: http://www.example.com/api/search?name=test&page=1, headers: (null) }
```

Error for iOS 8.0: `Error 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: What is the actual error?  Those messages don't seem to be saying that anything is wrong.

Comment: Getting <html><title> Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title></html>.

Comment: Are you able to capture the full URL at the server end and show us the difference?

Comment: @trojanfoe the differences are:

For earlier version we are getting: 
http://www.example.com/api/search?name=test&page=1
For IOS 8.0 we are getting:
http://www.example.com/api/search?name=test&page=1, headers: (null)

Comment: Where are you seeing "headers: (null)"?  Also, how are you sending the request?

Comment: @PhillipMills when we are set url in "nsmutableurlrequest" like "[urlRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];" then getting "headers : (null)" with given url.

Comment: OK, so the "headers: (null)" is output from a `NSLog()` statement of an object.  Are you talking to your own server?  Can you see what the server is logging as an incoming request?

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue. will you find any solution?

Comment: @Nandha no :(

If you will find any solution then share with me :)

Comment: Hi, Have you got any solution ?

Comment: Actually i was also having the same issue in my code, but I am wondering how it is affecting your response. Is the response different in ios7 and ios8?

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding that log. It just means that

```
URL = "http://www.example.com/api/search?name=test&page=1"
```

and

```
headers = null
```

What you should be debugging are the actual headers:

```
NSLog("%@", urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields);
```

Comment: Maybe, however shouldn't the OP be setting at least one header (i.e. `Content-Type`) so the server knows what it's getting?

Comment: @trojanfoe and John Estropia actually we are calling google map api
when we are using "[urlRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];" and print a nslog then getting url like "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?key=yourkey&location=lat,long&radius=radius,%20headers:%20(null)"

Comment: @AshutoshSrivastava Why are you drip-feeding details to us?  How about full disclosure right from the start?